# How to check all the elements that are visible in viewport of mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, viewport

I am trying to check if the div containing the image are in the viewport.

I tried following code

```
$.fn.is_on_screen = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
CheckIt();

function CheckIt() {
    $('.target').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('img').attr('data-src')) { // if target element exists in DOM
            if ($(this).is_on_screen()) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
                if ($(this).find('img').attr('data-src')) {
                    var source = $('.target').find('img').attr('data-src');

                    $('.target').find('img').attr('src', source);
                    $(this).find('.log').html('<div class="alert alert-success">target element is visible on screen</div>');

                }
                // log info     
            } else {

                $(this).find('.log').html('<div class="alert">target element is not visible on screen</div>'); // log info
            }
        }
    });

}
$(window).scroll(function () { // bind window scroll event
    CheckIt();
});
```

Its is rendering even those images that are below view port .

Any help why its happening would be appreciated

The [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8paydcd/9/)

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I have tried that @Alex bro . Doesn't work still i will give it a short

Comment: Try to look on this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: actually your code does work http://jsfiddle.net/p8paydcd/10/

Comment: I believe the reason there's issues on mobile is that viewports behave very differently on mobile.  I'm not sure what the best solution is though.